# linq group by id and sum of amount getting null(undefined)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var approverlist = _db.ApprvRejClaimTravelCashByApproverIdIPhone(ProjectSession.CompanyUserId, ProjectSession.CompanyId, Status).AsEnumerable().ToList();`
var results =
    from item in approverlist
    group item by item.ClaimId
        into g
        select new
        {
            ClaimId = g.Key,
            Name = g.First().Name,
            Amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount),
            Description = g.First().Description,
            Status = g.First().Status,
            CreatedDate = g.First().CreatedDate,
            SubmitedDate = g.First().SubmitedDate,
            FullName = g.First().FullName,
            ApproverStatus = g.First().ApproverStatus,
            CurrencySymbol = g.First().CurrencySymbol,
            chkbox = g.First().chkbox,
            IsHierarchy = g.First().IsHierarchy,
            ColumnCategory = g.First().ColumnCategory,
            ColumnCategoryCode = g.First().ColumnCategoryCode
        };

return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

getting undefined in column Amount when i bind this result to my kendo mvc grid,,,,any one have idea why this happens ?

Also tried below one but same result undefined :

```
var results = from x in approverlist
              group x.ClaimId by new { x.ClaimId, x.Name, x.Description, x.Status, x.CreatedDate, x.SubmitedDate, x.FullName, x.ApproverStatus, x.CurrencySymbol, x.chkbox, x.IsHierarchy, x.ColumnCategory, x.ColumnCategoryCode }
              into g
              select new { g.Key.ClaimId, g.Key.Name, Amount = g.Sum(), g.Key.Description, g.Key.Status, g.Key.CreatedDate, g.Key.SubmitedDate, g.Key.FullName, g.Key.ApproverStatus, g.Key.CurrencySymbol, g.Key.chkbox, g.Key.IsHierarchy, g.Key.ColumnCategory, g.Key.ColumnCategoryCode };
```

Comment: is Amount a value type or nullable? if you put s=> 1, do you get values counting?

Comment: its coming from my SP resultset like this :   
public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }

Comment: try putting s=>s.Amount??0 (which is zero when null)

Comment: but i have value in Amount column for all records , still i have to put that ?

Comment: Maybe you have on null value, or maybe the grid you use (that I have not used) is not good with nullables. I am not sure it fixes the thing for you, but I'm trying to debug. If it fixes, I will make it an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80243/discussion-between-kashyap-vyas-and-braim).